# Auto deploy github with action throug ssh return rsync exited with code 255

Tags: node.js, git, ssh, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to deploy my NodeJS GitHub project to my VPs using ssh, so I make this script in `.github/workflows` :

```yaml
  
name: Node CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Install Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: '10.x'
    - name: Install npm dependencies
      run: npm install
    - name: Run build task
      run: npm run build --if-present
    - name: Deploy to Server
      uses: easingthemes/ssh-deploy@v2.2.11
      env:
          SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          ARGS: "-rltgoDzvO --delete"
          SOURCE: "/"
          REMOTE_HOST: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          REMOTE_USER: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          TARGET: ${{ secrets.FOLDER_TARGET }}
          EXCLUDE: "/dist/, /node_modules/"
```

I enter every information in my secret repository key.
And to generate the ssh key, I'm using this command :
`ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 4096` with not paraphrase.
And I have passed the ~/.ssh/id_rsa` string inside SSH_KEY value

But after all of that, I have this error when run the action script:

```
Run easingthemes/ssh-deploy@v2.2.11
[general] GITHUB_WORKSPACE:  /home/runner/work/Litopia.fr/Litopia.fr
[SSH] Creating /home/runner/.ssh dir in  /home/runner/work/Litopia.fr/Litopia.fr
✅ [SSH] dir created.
[SSH] Creating /home/runner/.ssh/known_hosts file in  /home/runner/work/Litopia.fr/Litopia.fr
✅ [SSH] file created.
✅ Ssh key added to `.ssh` dir  /home/runner/.ssh/deploy_key
[Rsync] Starting Rsync Action: /home/runner/work/Litopia.fr/Litopia.fr// to ***@***:***
[Rsync] exluding folders /dist/,/node_modules/
⚠️ [Rsync] error:  rsync exited with code 255
⚠️ [Rsync] stderr:  Warning: Permanently added '***,82.65.27.189' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
***@***: Permission denied (publickey,password).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.3]

⚠️ [Rsync] stdout:  
⚠️ [Rsync] cmd:  rsync /home/runner/work/Litopia.fr/Litopia.fr// ***@***:*** --rsh "ssh -p 22 -i /home/runner/.ssh/deploy_key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" --recursive --exclude=/dist/ --exclude=/node_modules/ -rltgoDzvO --delete
 1: 0x9da7c0 node::Abort() [/home/runner/runners/2.278.0/externals/node12/bin/node]
 2: 0xa4e219  [/home/runner/runners/2.278.0/externals/node12/bin/node]
 3: 0xba5d59  [/home/runner/runners/2.278.0/externals/node12/bin/node]
 4: 0xba7b47 v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/home/runner/runners/2.278.0/externals/node12/bin/node]
 5: 0x13750d9  [/home/runner/runners/2.278.0/externals/node12/bin/node]
```

Comment: Did you add the USERNAME public key on server in /home/USERNAME/.ssh/authorized_keys ?
This is a ssh permission trouble, not related directly to rsync.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check first that, as mentioned in [`easingthemes/ssh-deploy` README](https://github.com/easingthemes/ssh-deploy), the public key part has been added to the `authorized_keys` file on the server that receives the deployment.

Try and test it with

```
ssh -Tv -i /home/runner/.ssh/deploy_key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $REMOTE_USER@$REMOTE_HOST
```

---

The [OP MrSolarius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12806467/mrsolarius) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68363866/auto-deploy-github-with-action-throug-ssh-return-rsync-exited-with-code-255/68436208#comment121163851_68436208):

> I have use my private key instead of my public key, so now it works.

Comment: I have use my private key instead of my public key, so now it works ^^'

Comment: @MrSolarius OK, good catch. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Using my private key instead the public worked!

Answer (score 1):

This issue also happened to me also. **What I did wrong was copied content from .ppk** file. After I opened **.pem file from Notepad** and copied the content it started working

Apart from that I had to enable SSH port from EC2 VPC groups to anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and struggled 1 week with this anomaly. Then I found at the GitHub easingteams/ssh-deploy repo issues the right hint: [GitHub](https://github.com/easingthemes/ssh-deploy/issues/175) There is mentioned that the private-key in `env: SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}` should have an extra empty line after the last one.

Comment: Good catch. [`easingthemes/ssh-deploy` issue 175](https://github.com/easingthemes/ssh-deploy/issues/175) looks promising: "We need an extra line after `-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`"